# codemirror.js:8236 Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, properties, undefined, typeerror, codemirror

I have a simple html site including CodeMirror.

https://jsfiddle.net/xsxo0xmd/

Unfortunately I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focused' of undefined
at Yo.prepareSelection (codemirror.js:8236)
at Yo.focus (codemirror.js:8321)
at new Po (codemirror.js:7266)
at Po (codemirror.js:7248)
at fiddle.jshell.net/:61
```

Any idea why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's just an issue of the current version.